# hibernate multiple update queries single transaction

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate with mysql db but having trouble with multiple updates in single transaction

Here is my code

```
public void  updateOEMUser(OEMUserDetailsDTO userDTO) throws Exception{
        Session session = GCCPersistenceMangerFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        String query = "update oemuserdata set full_name=\""+userDTO.getFullName()+ "\" ,contact_no=\""+userDTO.getContactNo() + "\" where user_id="+userDTO.getUserId();
        String query1 = "update usermasterdata set account_status="+userDTO.getAccountStatus() + " ,user_name=\"" + userDTO.getUserName() + "\" where user_id="+userDTO.getUserId();
        Query q = session.createSQLQuery(query);
        Query q1 = session.createSQLQuery(query1);
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        q.executeUpdate();
        q1.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("HibernateException_updateOEMUser");
    }finally {
        session.close(); 
    }
}
```

The code works but when I make "q1.executeUpdate()" fail the record in "oemuserdata" is getting locked in Mysql.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why aint you using HQL for performing update?

Comment: How are you making q1.executeUpdate() fail?

Comment: @will - I added a breakpoint at the statement and disconnected the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Try using such kind of pattern.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("UPDATE  CLASSNAME_FIRST a ,");
query.append("CLASSNAME_SECOND b,");
query.append("SET a.full_name='"+userDTO.getFullName()",");
.....

int var = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: i dont think that queries have any problem cause not only my function works normally unless I make it fail, I have another function which behaves exactly same in  which I use POJO classes in queries and I use session.createQuery().

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didin't find the solution but I found out what's happening here.

When I remove the connection after successful execution of **q.executeUpdate()**  exception is thrown at the execution of **q1.executeUpdate()** and after catch block it goes in final block and tries to execute **session.close()**, but since there is no DB connectivity this also fails.

But Mysql still has the lock requested by **q.executeUpdate()**. That's why the row is locked until Mysql releases lock itself.